# Retrieving data from multiple rows on same field in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem in my "Android" development apps.

I tried to retrieve some data from 2 tables eg:

```
post ( post_title, post_desc )

postmeta ( postmeta_value )
```

postmeta_ID is the foreign key. I wanted to retrieve some specific ( post title, post desc and all postmeta value ) data from post ID == 1 from both table.

I have used this this syntax but always says "error near SELECT":

```
String q2 = " SELECT  post_content, post_title, "
    + "land.postmeta_value landValue, "
    + "price.postmeta_value priceValue, "
    + "bedroom.postmeta_value bedroomValue, "
    + "bathroom.postmeta_value bathroomValue, "
    + "pool.postmeta_value poolValue,"
    + " type.postmeta_value typeValue, "
    + "ownership.postmeta_value ownershipValue, "
    + "location.postmeta_value locationValue, "
    + "poolType.postmeta_value poolTypeValue, "
    + "carPort.postmeta_value carPortValue, "
    + "so.postmeta_value soValue, "
    + "ct.postmeta_value ctValue "
    + "FROM post "
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta land ON post._id=land.postmeta_ID "
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta price ON post._id=price.postmeta_ID "
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta bedroom ON post._id=bedroom.postmeta_ID "
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta bathroom ON post._id=bathroom.postmeta_ID "
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta pool ON post._id=pool.postmeta_ID"
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta type ON post._id=type.postmeta_ID"
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta ownership ON post._id=ownership.postmeta_ID"
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta location ON post._id=location.postmeta_ID"
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta poolType ON post._id=poolType.postmeta_ID "
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta carPort ON post._id=carPort.postmeta_ID"
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta so ON post._id=so.postmeta_ID"
    + "INNER JOIN postmeta ct ON post._id=ct.postmeta_ID WHERE post_ID = 2";
```

When I used only 3 of inner join, it's fine... But when it comes to this, always says error.

Is there something wrong in my syntax ? Or is there  a maximum restriction on using the inner join on a syntax ?

I cannot attach the table structure screenshot since I don't have 10 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I used this syntax:

```
SELECT post_title, post_content, postmeta_key, postmeta_value 
FROM post INNER JOIN postmeta land ON post._id=land.postmeta_ID 
WHERE postmeta_ID = " + postID + " AND postmeta_key IN ( 
    'landSize', 'buildingSize', 'propertyPrice', 'propertyBedroom', 
    'propertyBathroom', 'pool', 'propertyType', 'propertyOwnership', 
    'propertyLocation', 'propertyPoolType', 'propertyCarPort', 
    'propertySpecialOffer', 'propertyCurrencyType' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have a space at the end of every line of your SQL String or else you'll end up sending things like:

```
"INNER JOIN postmeta carPort ON post._id=carPort.postmeta_IDINNER JOIN postmeta so ON post._id=so.postmeta_ID"
```

To the SQL Interpreter, which will probably spit that back out.

Comment: I have tried your advice, but still no luck... And it freezes while I run the "SQL" using mozilla SQLite plugin.

Comment: It freezes because this query generates billions of output rows. But that would be another question; *this* question is answered.

Comment: Oh I see.... I thought it was some restrictions that prohibit to use too many inner join there... But I have found the solution by my own like this:

"SELECT post_title, post_content, postmeta_key, postmeta_value FROM post INNER JOIN postmeta land ON post._id=land.postmeta_ID WHERE postmeta_ID = " + postID + " AND postmeta_key IN ( 'landSize', 'buildingSize', 'propertyPrice', 'propertyBedroom', 'propertyBathroom', 'pool', 'propertyType', 'propertyOwnership', 'propertyLocation', 'propertyPoolType', 'propertyCarPort', 'propertySpecialOffer', 'propertyCurrencyType' )"

Thanks for helping me @CL.